# Adding an if condition to a for loop

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make it work on every number divisible by three.
here's my code:

```
var number = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]; 


    for(var i = 0; i<10 ; i++) {
        if (i % 3 === 0) {
            console.log(color[i]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Trying to make what work exactly. What are you trying to do with the color array inside your if statement

Answer (score 3):

I think you need to use `number[i] % 3 === 0`. And what is the `color` there in your code? Change it into `number`.

```js
var number = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]; 

for(var i = 0; i<10 ; i++) {
    if (number[i] % 3 === 0) {
        console.log(number[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: still a no go it even when i add that

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
var number = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]; 


    for(var i = 0; i<10 ; i++) {
        if (i % 3 === 0) {
            console.log(i);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Where is `number` used?